# Weight effect when dining out

Tags: weight-loss, weight-gain, weights, bodyweight

I measure my weight every morning. I find that my weight increases by 2 to 3 pounds if I have my dinner at a restaurant instead of home the night before, even the portions are about the same.

May I know if there is any reason behind this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Rapid increases in weight over a night is usually caused by water retention. Various things can cause the body to hold more water for longer, so the overall body weight goes up.  The effect can last a few hours to a couple days depending on the cause.

The most common culprit is salt because restaurants love putting salt on everything. It also makes you thirsty so you drink more. Starchy carbs like potatoes will also cause water retention.

A secondary cause is you may be underestimating the portion size of the meal. Eyeballing portions is a learned skill which is why some people will actually bring mini scales. Restaurants sometimes also add oils that go unaccounted for.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. What will you suggest in order for me to reduce the amount of water being retained after the meal. Thanks again

Comment: @George Sauces tend to be the highest in salt, so I would avoid any foods that might have sauce.  Though personally I don't worry about it.  The effects are temporary and don't mean anything regarding weightloss.